# Wondering about the components in a chinese amplifier

Tags: amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

I just bought an SMSL Audio SA98E.

It is a switched power supply based on the TDA7498E. When I googled images of it I saw that they had different internals.  Different components inside.

Could this change the sound?

Oh and what do the metal doughnuts do?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: The metal doughnuts are important for jam sessions.

Comment: But what do they do?

Comment: The metal doughnuts are toroid inductors.  I'm guessing this is a Class D amplifier which uses a form of PWM modulation to achieve very high efficiency.  The inductors are used to remove the PWM carrier frequency from the output signal.

Comment: It is switched power supply based on the STMicroelectronics TDA7498E amp chip do you think the different components might change the way it sounds? is that heatsink sufficient for 80  watts rms  per channel into 4 ohms? it seems kinda small

Comment: It is an **amplifier**, not a power supply.

Comment: Oh but it is pretty similarto  a swtiched power suppyl

Comment: In many cases the metal doughnuts keep the magic blue smoke circling, like a fusion power plant. While in this case, the blue smoke containers in the middle seem big enough to retain it alone. *scnr*

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine with 15% loss max at 2x160W Class D = 48W , it will need forced air with a tiny case fan with a plenum to maximize the air velocity over the fins.

Here the coils are twinned to support the current needed with 8 coils.  Basically they need 2 per channel for differential Class D switching to double the voltage and power.

[image]

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda7498e.pdf

Comment: 48 watts at 8 ohms or 4 ohms? and the heatsink in the unit aint good enough to cool it?  Cause the powerbrick i got with the amp is 36volts and 5a so 180 watts I know that the chip is BTL using four channels so a 4 ohm load would be seen as a 2 ohm load by the amplifier

Comment: No this doubles the supply voltage across the speaker with a differential output